# 2D fit of a model to an image in Python

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, imaging

I want to fit a model (here a 2D Gaussian but it could be something else) with an image in Python.

Trying to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` I have some questions. See below.

Let's start with some functions :

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.signal import argrelmax

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

from tifffile import TiffFile

# 2D Gaussian model
def func(xy, x0, y0, sigma, H):

    x, y = xy

    A = 1 / (2 * sigma**2)
    I = H * np.exp(-A * ( (x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2))
    return I

# Generate 2D gaussian
def generate(x0, y0, sigma, H):

    x = np.arange(0, max(x0, y0) * 2 + sigma, 1)
    y = np.arange(0, max(x0, y0) * 2 + sigma, 1)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    I = func((xx, yy), x0=x0, y0=y0, sigma=sigma, H=H)

    return xx, yy, I

def fit(image, with_bounds):

    # Prepare fitting
    x = np.arange(0, image.shape[1], 1)
    y = np.arange(0, image.shape[0], 1)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    # Guess intial parameters
    x0 = int(image.shape[0]) # Middle of the image
    y0 = int(image.shape[1]) # Middle of the image
    sigma = max(*image.shape) * 0.1 # 10% of the image
    H = np.max(image) # Maximum value of the image
    initial_guess = [x0, y0, sigma, H]

    # Constraints of the parameters
    if with_bounds:
        lower = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        upper = [image.shape[0], image.shape[1], max(*image.shape), image.max() * 2]
        bounds = [lower, upper]
    else:
        bounds = [-np.inf, np.inf]

    pred_params, uncert_cov = curve_fit(func, (xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()), image.ravel(),
                                        p0=initial_guess, bounds=bounds)

    # Get residual
    predictions = func((xx, yy), *pred_params)
    rms = np.sqrt(np.mean((image.ravel() - predictions.ravel())**2))

    print("True params : ", true_parameters)
    print("Predicted params : ", pred_params)
    print("Residual : ", rms)

    return pred_params

def plot(image, params):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.BrBG, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')

    ax.scatter(params[0], params[1], s=100, c="red", marker="x")

    circle = Circle((params[0], params[1]), params[2], facecolor='none',
            edgecolor="red", linewidth=1, alpha=0.8)
    ax.add_patch(circle)
```

```py
# Simulate and fit model
true_parameters = [50, 60, 10, 500]
xx, yy, image = generate(*true_parameters)

# The fit performs well without bounds
params = fit(image, with_bounds=False)
plot(image, params)
```

Output :

```
True params :  [50, 60, 10, 500]
Predicted params :  [  50.   60.   10.  500.]
Residual :  0.0
```

[image]

Now if we do the same fit with bounds (or constraints).

```py
# The fit is really bad with bounds
params = fit(image, with_bounds=True)
plot(image, params)
```

Output :

```
True params :  [50, 60, 10, 500]
Predicted params :  [ 130.          130.            0.72018729    1.44948159]
Residual :  68.1713019773
```

[image]

Why the fit doesn't perform well when I add bounds ?

---

Now another thing I don't understand. Why this fit is not robust when it's applied on real data ? See below.

```py
# Load some real data
image = TiffFile("../data/spot.tif").asarray()
plt.imshow(image, aspect='equal', origin='lower', interpolation="none", cmap=plt.cm.BrBG)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

```py
# Fit is not possible without bounds
params = fit(image, with_bounds=False)
plot(image, params)
```

Output :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3187b53d622d> in <module>()
      1 # Fit is not possible without bounds
----> 2 params = fit(image, with_bounds=False)
      3 plot(image, params)

<ipython-input-11-f14c9dec72f2> in fit(image, with_bounds)
     54 
     55     pred_params, uncert_cov = curve_fit(func, (xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()), image.ravel(),
---> 56                                         p0=initial_guess, bounds=bounds)
     57 
     58     # Get residual

/home/hadim/local/conda/envs/ws/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, **kwargs)
    653         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)
    654         if ier not in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
--> 655             raise RuntimeError("Optimal parameters not found: " + errmsg)
    656     else:
    657         res = least_squares(func, p0, args=args, bounds=bounds, method=method,

RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000.
```

And

```py
# Fit works but is not accurate at all with bounds
params = fit(image, with_bounds=True)
plot(image, params)
```

Output :

```
True params :  [50, 60, 10, 500]
Predicted params :  [   19.31770886    10.52153346    37.          1296.22524248]
Residual :  83.1944464761
```

[image]

Comment: Not that I can also reproduce the real data case by adding noise to the fake data with `image += np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1e-2, size=image.shape)`.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things, first, your initial parameters `x0` and `y0` are wrong, they are not at the middle of the image, but at the border, they should be

```
x0 = int(image.shape[0])/2 # Middle of the image
y0 = int(image.shape[1])/2 # Middle of the image
```

Having them at the border of the image might produce some issues in the constrained case by not giving it room to move in some directions. This is speculation of mine and depend on the fitting method.

Also speaking of methods, `curve_fit` can use either of three: `lm`, `trf` and `dogbox` from the [scipy least_squares documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html):

> - ‘trf’ : Trust Region Reflective algorithm, particularly suitable for large sparse problems with bounds. Generally robust method.
> - ‘dogbox’ : dogleg algorithm with rectangular trust regions, typical use case is small problems with bounds. Not recommended for problems with rank-deficient Jacobian.
> - ‘lm’ : Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm as implemented in MINPACK. Doesn’t handle bounds and sparse Jacobians. Usually the most efficient method for small unconstrained problems.

`curve_fit` [will use different methods for bounded and unbounded cases](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

> Default is ‘lm’ for unconstrained problems and ‘trf’ if bounds are provided

So I suggest defining a method to use, I got good results with either `trf` and `dogbox` with your example after correcting the initial parameters, but you should check which method works better with your real data.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [lightweight class](https://github.com/david-hoffman/peaks/blob/master/gauss2d.py) to do exactly this. Bounds are not implemented very well but this could be changed to suit your needs.

There's three main problems you're having here:

1. You're not modeling an *offset* in your data. From looking at your image the background is about 1300-1400 counts.
2. The initial guess parameters are not good estimates (as pointed out by @Noel)
3. You're fitting much more data than necessary, I would suggest choosing the region around the peak. If you make better guesses of the initial parameters you can restrict your fit to a window centered on your guess `x0` and `y0`.

There are two ways of solving problem 1:

- Estimate the background and subtract it from your data (the `median` or `mode` of the data is a good bet, [my class](https://github.com/david-hoffman/peaks/blob/master/utils.py) uses the [`RANSAC`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html) algorithm provided by `sklearn` to estimate this in a more sophisticated way)
- Or you could model the background directly.

For problem 2. you can use `skimage`'s [blob detection algorithms](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_blob.html). I've also written another [class](https://github.com/david-hoffman/peaks/blob/master/peakfinder.py) that wraps `skimage`'s DOG algorithm to make this easier. Once you solve problem 2 problem 3 is solved as well.